# 'Converting' from an equation to a congruence when the dividend and modulus share common factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

I am trying to figure out how I would show in a more 'mathematical' way that $x_1p\bmod{x_1x_2}$ will only give results (remainders) that are either 0 or a multiple of $x_1$. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are prime numbers.

I came to that conclusion by using an equation to calculate the remainder: for $a\bmod{n}$, $r = a - n\lfloor{\frac{a}{n}}\rfloor$. So for my case: $r = x_1p - x_1x_2\lfloor{\frac{x_1p}{x_1x_2}}\rfloor$. Then I simplified and factored to get $r = x_1(p - \lfloor{\frac{p}{x_2}}\rfloor)$, which is just $x_1$ times an integer. So that is saying that the remainder is always going to be some multiple of $x_1$ or 0. I am not sure how to write this out using congruences or in a more formal way. I basically want to write this out how a proof/textbook would so that the 'which is just $x_1$ times an integer' portion is clearer.

I started doing this type of math a few days ago so this may be something totally obvious that I overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: A special case of the **mod Distributive Law:**  $\ ca\bmod cn =\, c(a\bmod n)\ $ - [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally $\, c>0\,\Rightarrow\, ca\bmod cn\, =\, c(a\bmod n)\quad $ [[mod Distributive Law]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)

**Proof** $\ $ Scaling remainder $\,a\bmod n\,$ by $\,c\,$ and invoking remainder *uniqueness* yields

$$\begin{align}  a\bmod n\ =\, &\ \ a-qn\\
\Rightarrow\  0\ \le\, &\ \ a-qn\,\ <\,\ n\\
\Rightarrow\  0\ \le\, &\,ca-qcn < cn\\
\Rightarrow\  ca\bmod cn\ =\, &\, ca-qcn\, =\, c(a\!-\!qn)\, =\, c(a\bmod n)\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea. You want to factor out the $x_1$ to show that the result is a multiple of $x_1$. In short, we have the following:

Suppose $a\equiv x_1p\pmod{x_1x_2}$, then $a-x_1p=kx_1x_2$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Hence, $a=x_1(p+kx_2)$, so $a$ is a multiple of $x_1$ (this includes the case of $a=0$).

Comment: Shouldn't we be proving something about $a\bmod{x_1x_2}$, instead of just $a$ though?

Comment: @Slade $a$ represents the remainder of $x_1p$ when divided by $x_1x_2$, and we have just shown that $a$ is a multiple of $x_1$. Is this not what you wanted to show?

Comment: So I'm starting at: $x_1p\bmod{x_1x_2} = a$. And since the answer, $a$, is definitely less than $x_1x_2$, we can say that $a = a\bmod{x_1x_2}$ right? And then the rest of what you said follows?

Comment: @Slade Well if $a$ is the remainder after division of $x_1x_2$, then yes $a<x_1x_2$. And because $\equiv\pmod n$ defines an equivalence relation for $n>1$, we have $a\equiv a\pmod n$ for any $a\in\Bbb Z$ by symmetry.

Comment: I think it's cleared up for me now. Thank you!